# aws s3 file upload using aws-sdk nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to aws s3 bucket from user {angularjs frontend} and parsing the file to nodejs api route but keep getting error:"TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined".. I'm able to upload file from postman(chrome extension) by sending post request with file but i cant figure out how to parse file from angular to node js. Heres what im doing:

**// NODEJS code:**

```
router.post('/user/upload', multipartMiddleware, function(req, res){
        var file = req.files.file;
        var body = fs.createReadStream(file.path);
        var filename =  'post7/media.jpg';

        var s3bucket3 = new AWS.S3();
        s3bucket3.createBucket({Bucket: 'artistarc-user-post-media'}, function() {
          var data = {Bucket: 'artistarc-user-post-media', Key: filename, Body: body};
          s3bucket3.putObject(data, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
              console.log("Error uploading data: ", err);
            } else {
              console.log("Successfully uploaded data to Bucket");
            }
          });
        });
        res.end('Uploaded');
    });
```

**// ANGULARJS controller:**

```
myApp.controller('galleryController', ['$scope', 'Api', function($scope, Api){

    console.log('galleryController');
    $scope.file = [];
    $scope.uploadFile = function(){
        Api.MediaUpload.save({}, $scope.file, function(){
            console.log('uploaded');
        });
    }
}]);
```

**// EJS tempelate**

```
<form>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-trans btn-sm" ng-click = "uploadFile()">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    Upload
                </button>
                <input type = "file" name = "file"  ng-model="file" file/></div>
</form>
```

****I also tried using directive , but it too resulted in error. here is what i tried**

**//directive 'file'**

```
myApp.directive('file', ['$scope', function($scope){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          file: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, el, attrs){
          el.bind('change', function(event){
            var files = event.target.files;
            var file = files[0];
            scope.file = file;
            scope.$parent.file = file;
            scope.$apply();
          });
        }
    };
}]);﻿
```

Comment: As a sidenote, the awesome Amazon lets you upload files directly from the clientside, as in from the users browsers, without it ever going through your server, and with the new Lambda functions you can change the files directly in the bucket as they are uploaded, for instance generating new images of different sizes etc.

Comment: Thanks adeno.. are you referring to aws-sdk-js? I tried that and it worked. but I'm confused..will it be safe if i use upload part from client side instead of server side?

Comment: Just as safe as anything else, and you don't get the added traffic on your server, the files go straight to AWS. Of course that also means that if AWS is down, it fails, but chances of that are probably slim.

Comment: ok then client side it is.

Comment: Silly question, but I have to ask...is `galleryController` assigned to your form? Because if not, that would explain why `$scope.file` was undefined. You can test by opening up your web inspector, clicking on the form element, and typing `angular.element($0).scope()` in your console. Check to be sure the scope contains a `file` property.